# STL List - Datatype as a pointer object

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointers, stl, abstract-base-class

I'm having a problem using inheritance and the STL list library...

Say, I have an abstract base class with two derived classes (where all comparison operators are defined). The list is declared as

```
list<StoreItem*> items;
```

I'm inserting a derived class (of the abstract base class, StoreItem) called either Food or Clothing. I make a new StoreItem pointer that's about to be inserted:

```
StoreItem* item = new Food(arguments here);
```

Now, I'm wanting to insert this new item (in order) to the list, and my attempt is this:

```
list<StoreItem*>::iterator iter;
for (iter = inventory.begin(); iter != inventory.end(); iter++)
{
    if (*item < **iter)
        break; // break out to insert
}

inventory.insert(iter, item);
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Also, how would I pull the information from the inventory? (ex: Food tempFruit(**iter) using the copy constructor).

Thank you in advance! Have a good day.

Comment: What exactly is the question?  Are you asking if it is fundamentally correct/wrong to perform comparisons the way that you are doing so, or are you having a problem with the code?

Comment: Did you define operator `<` for your class?

Comment: The question I'm mainly getting at is that I don't know why when I do this:

    Food tempMovie(**iter);

It asks for the definition of the Food::Food(const StoreItem*), when the datatype of the **iter that was inserted was clearly Food in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that the item you are pulling from the list is a `Food` instance; however, the compiler doesn't know that.  When you construct a new instance of `Food` from an item in the list (an item with apparent type `StoreItem`), you are trying to call `Food::Food(const StoreItem)` or something compatible.  Why? Because the iterator points to a `StoreItem*` that *could* be an instance of a `StoreItem` object, or an instance of any class derived from `StoreItem`, such as `Food`.

As other posters have commented, polymorphism is *a* key to success.  Do you really need to know that the item is a `Food`?  If not, then access the interface shared by all store items (like price, serial-number, etc.).  If you need to know something specific about the item, then you can try to infer its type:

```
Food *food = dynamic_cast<Food*>(*iter);
if (food != NULL) {
   // perform food related logic
   std::cout << "Ingredients: " << food->ingredients() << std::endl;
}
else {
   std::cout << "I can't eat that!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This was very similar to my answer, Nathan. My answer I got after tinkering around and thinking of which side should have the higher precedence and be executed first, I did ((Food*)(*iter))->food_method();. Thanks man!

Comment: I'm glad it works for you.  Just be careful with C-style casting.  You can may be able to cast the contents of the iterator to a `Food` pointer, but that doesn't mean that it is *actually* pointing to a `Food` object.  This could lead to unexpected segfaults, unpredictable behavior, memory corruption, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This will work, provided you've defined `StoreItem::operator<`, but there's another way that might be a little better. The STL has sorting down cold. You could define `<` for `StoreItem*`, then use `list<...>::sort()`.

(And you've probably already thought of defining your own `SortedItemList` class that handles the sorting internally.)

And yes, `tempMovie(**iter)` would work, among other ways.

**EDIT:**

I think I spoke too soon about pulling something out of the inventory. This works:

```
list<StoreItem *>::iterator citr = items.begin();

Food *fp = dynamic_cast<Food *>(*citr);

Food ff(*fp);
```

Note that you have to know that this `StoreItem*` actually points to a `Food`-- if it points to a `Clothing` you'll get a segmentation fault or worse. To find out, you could implement your own `StoreItem::whatTypeAmI()`, or use C++'s run-time type identification:

```
#include <typeinfo>
...
Food a;
StoreItem *sp = *citr;
if(typeid(*sp)==typeid(a))
{
  // it's a Food
}
```

(Be aware that you can do a lot with a `StoreItem*` or `StoreItem&` without knowing it's type-- polymorphism is your friend.)

Comment: This one helped the most; however, I'm having an issue actually pulling the information from the list as one of the derived classes, unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

If you can define a comparison operator between two *pointers* to your base class, you can get an ordered collection without writing any other code. Depending on your application you might want a set or a heap, maybe even a map. Here's the idiom to do it... (base is publicly derived from string).

```
template<>
struct std::less<base*>
{
   bool operator()(const base* lhs, const base* rhs) const
   {
      return *lhs < *rhs;
   }
};

typedef set<base*> S;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    base able(std::string("able"));
    base baker(std::string("baker"));
    base charlie(std::string("charlie"));

    S inventory;
    inventory.insert(&charlie);
    inventory.insert(&able);
    inventory.insert(&baker);

    for (S::iterator i = inventory.begin(); i != inventory.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << **i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:
able
baker
charlie

It's possible to mill around for a while before discovering this idiom. What's going on is that you're specializing the library template std::less for T=base*; this then slots as if by magic into the default comparator argument for std::set (or other ordered containers).

Comment: This helped me understand a different concept; however, did not help me the way I wanted. Thank you, though! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of homebrewing any solution you could resort to [`boost::ptr_list`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_list.html). It makes life a lot easier if you intend to store pointers in STL like containers. Then all you need is to define `operator<` for whatever item you are trying to insert. Remember that `ptr_list` is not intended to be used with shared ownership. To achieve this use `std::shared_ptrS` in a `std::list` and specialize `std::less` for your `shared_ptr` type.

Answer (score 0):

With a comparison function defined for pointers to `StoreItem` you can shorten your insertion code like so:

```
bool less_ptr( const StoreItem*& lhs, const StoreItem*& rhs )
{
    return *lhs < *rhs;
}
```

Insertion:

```
StoreItem* item = new Food(arguments here);
inventory.insert( std::upper_bound( inventory.begin(), inventory.end(), item, less_ptr ), item);
```

`std::upper_bound` (`#include <algorithm>`) assumes your list is sorted, so this applies if you keep your list sorted at all times.

As to pulling the data back out, there are two things to consider:

1. If you re-create the objects using a copy constructor, you're creating new objects and changing them won't change the objects in the list, so it's better to use pointers
2. You have to split your code path depending on the type of the object stored

You can do this:

```
Food* foodObj = NULL;
Clothing* clothesObj = NULL;

list<StoreItem *>::iterator it = inventory.find( /* something */ );
StoreItem* item = *it;

item->DoSomethingWithAnyStoreItem(); // It's best to only use such methods

// But if you need something only a derived class has...
foodObj = dynamic_cast<Food*>(item);
clothesObj = dynamic_cast<Clothes*>(item);

if( foodObj != NULL )
{
    foodObj->DoSomethingWithFood();
    Food newFood( *foodObj );
    newFood.DoSomethingWithCopyOfFood();
}
else if( clothesObj != NULL )
{
    clothesObj->DoSomethingWithClothes();
}
else
{
    // It's neither Food, nor Clothes
}
```